# simply connected abelian Lie groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Is there any simple proof of the fact that: Up to isomorphism $\mathbb R^n$ is the only simply-connected abelian Lie group?

By simple proof I mean using only basic concepts from groups and topology.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729468/the-description-of-abelian-lie-groups

Comment: Yes I have seen this. But I want a proof without even knowing that Abelian  Lie groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n\times T^m$. Is that possible?

Comment: I thought that you wanted simple proofs, and that link offers one.

Comment: I was trying to solve exercise number 18 here (and he starts with proving that then only simply connected abelian Lie groups are $\mathbb R^n$) https://books.google.ca/books?id=S_7lBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&dq=Let+G+be+an+n%E2%80%93dimensional+Abelian+connected+Lie+group&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq56-4w-nLAhUjnIMKHQYNA3UQ6wEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Let%20G%20be%20an%20n%E2%80%93dimensional%20Abelian%20connected%20Lie%20group&f=false

Comment: @Batominovski I am trying to understand the proof you have directed me to. But I need some explanation on the followings: why the map $g\rightarrow G$ is a local homeo.? Why the discrete subgroups are on the forom $\Lambda=\mathbf Z x_1+\cdots + \mathbf Z x_n$ and why $x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathfrak g$ should be linearly independent? Thanks so much indeed!

Comment: The exponential map is always a local diffeomorphism (you can try to use the Inverse Function Theorem to verify this).  The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is isomorphic as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space to $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $d$ is the dimension of $G$.  Then, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247528/discrete-subgroups-are-lattices will answer your question.